# add a view to window in react native

Tags: react-native, view, window, subview

I'm developing a react native app primarily for android. I am trying to add a sticky view to the window of the phone, as in iOS, where I can easily access the Window and add a subview to it. But I am struggling with how to do it with `react-native`.

Comment: or in another word on top of all view controllers or activities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that by using [`position: 'absolute'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#position) and [`zIndex`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#zindex).

Wrap the whole app with a single view and add to it `style={{position: absolute}}`

See an example here:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 999}}>...</>
  <SomeView/>
</View>
```